# How to make a custom conditional formatting formula point to the contents of a cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with a custom formula that changes the colour of different cells based on the value in the dates column. I also frequently have to change the formula based on different times of the month.

I would like the formula to point to a cell eg A1 so that whenever I change the contents of A1, the custom formula itself will change.

Currently the custom conditional formatting formula is `=E2>=TODAY() -21`

I alternate between this and `=AND(E2>DATE(2019,3,23),E2<DATE(2019,4,20))`

I've tried to use `=INDIRECT(A1)` as the formula, with A1 cell content `=E2>=TODAY() -21` but this doesn't work. I would really appreciate any tips on how to get this working.

Comment: can you share your sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**custom formula:**

```
=IF((($A$1="=E2>=TODAY()-21")*(E2>=TODAY()-21))+
    (($A$1="=AND(E2>DATE(2019,3,23),E2<DATE(2019,4,20))")*((E2>DATE(2019,3,23))*(E2<DATE(2019,4,20)))),1)
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12B-c3KBggTdKU-2iikFvyfKZnWCiCUQ3Fk06EP-zV4o/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this later. I had a quick look earlier but it gave me an error on Data validation but i'll investigate further

Comment: Thanks for the response but I've had no joy with it :( I've attached the link to a demo sheet if you could point me in the right direction? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hzan32p1piS7bp5ZV13WgTmylOWDNdP4G3lQb5wE0pk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Amazing!! It works perfectly, thank you sooo much :)